# No such property: compile for class: java.lang.String in android studio

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

My project was working fine till last month but now its not running, for some unknown reasons it gives a message `No such property: compile for class: java.lang.String`  in app level build.gradle. My project remain untouched for a almost a month. Below is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.PSS.pssreminder"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.+'
    compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:+'
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:+'.
    compile 'com.bignerdranch.android:recyclerview-multiselect:+'
    compile 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:+'

}
```

Can you please help me out to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace all `compile` keywords with `implementation`. `compile` has been removed and replaced by `implementation` in gradle distributions. It should look like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.+'
    implementation 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:+'
    implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:+'.
    implementation 'com.bignerdranch.android:recyclerview-multiselect:+'
    implementation 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:+'
}
```

Comment: sorry Sir but that's for android studio 3.+ and I am using android studio 2.3.3

Comment: I would highly recommend you to update your Android Studio & Gradle plugin as huge improvements are released over the long time :)